# Push notifications not working but return status says it does

Tags: windows-phone-7

I successfuly managed to make push notifications (tile and toast) work on my device. But after a few days, it's not working anymore. However I get a good return status :

```
array(3) { ["X-SubscriptionStatus"]=> string(6) "Active" ["X-NotificationStatus"]=> string(8) "Received" ["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"]=> string(9) "Connected" }
```

I tried to put the device in airplane mode, with no wifi, and I get

```
array(3) { ["X-SubscriptionStatus"]=> string(6) "Active" ["X-NotificationStatus"]=> string(8) "Received" ["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"]=> string(16) "TempDisconnected" }
```

So it's "kind of" working, right ? How come I don't see any notifications ? How can I debug further ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone team blog talks about it:

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/02/17/push-notification-status.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have heard a lot of people having similar problems. Sometimes a Factory reset of the device seems to work, but the error often returns (especially after a reboot).

Is it working on the emulator?

Comment: I works on the Simulator, after uninstalling the app, rebooting and reinstalling, I works again (for how long ?). I upvoted your answer, but I'm keeping the question open in hope that someone will explain the issue